# Linq Query jumps out of foreach

Tags: linq

I have a Linq query, I want to return the `RegistrationID` (`GUID`) and an email. when the query gets to the `foreach` it jumps out on the value.

Can you tell me how the query should be wrote.

```
using( var fbdc = new FBDataContext() )
{
    var query = ( from q in fbdc.Registrations
              where q.BookingDateTime == DateTime.Now.AddDays( -1 )
              select new
              {
                  q.RegistrationID,
                  q.Email
              } );

    foreach( var value in query )
    {
        registrationId = value.RegistrationID;
        email = value.Email;
    }
}
```

Plus, I'm not sure if the query would work. Is there a way to test this?
The `BookingDateTime` is a `DateTime` so thought this would work as I only want the files from yesterday. Could I use a more exact expression to query the date(30/09/2014)?

Comment: if you worry about the time, just use `<` and compare with Today (which the time is `00:00:00`). `q.BookingDateTime < DateTime.Today`

Comment: No problem with your query, just that you could use  "q.BookingDateTime .Date == DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays( -1 )"

Comment: `AddDays` is not supported in L2S

Comment: Thank you the < and > works

Answer (score -1):

You can use it by as below:

```
var query = ( from q in fbdc.Registrations
          where q.BookingDateTime == DateTime.Now.AddDays( -1 )
          select new
          {
              q.RegistrationID,
              q.Email
          } ).AsEnumerable();
```

Comment: Please tell exactly how you expect calling `AsEnumerable` just before enumerating the result will make any difference.